# Fill values in pandas data frame to make dataframe contiguous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a data frame of the form

```
   day  hour  variantid    eventType    counts
0   8   14    variantid1    clicked     63
1   8   14    variantid1    served      5783
2   8   14    variantid2    clicked     28
3   8   14    variantid2    served      4919
4   8   15    variantid2    served      268
```

Now since there is no corresponding value for `'clicked'` event for `variantid2`  at hour `15` on day `8`, it is hard for me to plot values correctly. How do I explicitly add the row `day=8 , hour=15  variantid=variantid2 eventType=clicked` to `count=0` using a method like `fillna` on this dataframe? (I'm only guessing we'd use `fillna`).

I am not quite sure how to do this?

Also following up on this question,  how would I change the value in the `counts` field to an aggregate number, which includes all events that happened until now?

So the above dataframe would be transformed into:

```
   day  hour    variantid    eventType  counts
0   8   14      variantid1   clicked    63
1   8   14      variantid1   served     5783
2   8   14      variantid2   clicked    28
3   8   14      variantid2   served     4919
4   8   15      variantid2   served     5187   # 4919 + 268
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second question (btw, you should only have one per post), the trick is to have your time column as the index and then unstack everything as MultiIndex columns.  You can then easily perform a `cumsum`:

```
df2 = (pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['day', 'hour', 'variantid', 'eventType']).counts.sum())
       .unstack(['variantid', 'eventType']))
>>> df2 
              counts                         
variantid variantid1        variantid2       
eventType    clicked served    clicked served
day hour                                     
8   14            63   5783         28   4919
    15           NaN    NaN        NaN    268

>>> df2.cumsum()
              counts                         
variantid variantid1        variantid2       
eventType    clicked served    clicked served
day hour                                     
8   14            63   5783         28   4919
    15           NaN    NaN        NaN   5187
```

To be honest, I'm not sure you meant in the first question.  Perhaps you want to take this dataframe, `fillna(0)` on the result, and then stack it back?

```
>>> df2.cumsum().fillna(0).stack(['variantid', 'eventType'])
                               counts
day hour variantid  eventType        
8   14   variantid1 clicked        63
                    served       5783
         variantid2 clicked        28
                    served       4919
    15   variantid1 clicked         0
                    served          0
         variantid2 clicked         0
                    served       5187
```